# How to break up an image into smaller tiles?

Tags: software, post-processing

I have some very big images that I would like to break into smaller tiles.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 11):

My first thought was [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), and indeed [it will work for this](http://ask.metafilter.com/82347/Break-an-image-into-tiles).  I had a 3504x2336 image, so to convert it into 16 images (a 4x4 tile set) I divided each dimension by 4 and then used:

```
convert -crop 876x584 IMG_5051.JPG tile_%d.jpg
```

And, here's a screenshot of performing that with "-crop 125x125" on a 500x500 image:

[image: file manager view of tiles and the original image]

Answer (score 2):

The [Rasterbator](http://homokaasu.org/rasterbator/) is free, open source, and available for Windows or as an online tool.

The output of Rasterbator is amplitude modulated (the dots vary in size) [halftone image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halftone). Thus it will not be a 1 for 1 representation of the original image. Rather it is meant to be displayed in a very very large format, and viewed from a long distance.

I once made a image the size of a standard door in my home. It was printed on a black and white laser printer, and assembled by me. The output was quite impressive, but it is an artistic look that does not fit in every case.

You can find more information about tiled printing solutions, as well as other options at the wikipedia article for [Tiled Printing here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiled_printing).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "a raster image", here? All current digital cameras produce raster images, so that's presumably the _input_ as well.

Comment: You bring up a good point :) For example, when I printed out a door size image with rasterbator, each 8.5x11 sheet was comprised of probably around 1-50 dots per inch. The best example of what this looks like is actually right behind the logo on the Rasterbator website. Big dots :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have MATLAB, you can tile your image very easily to any combination of tile sizes by loading the image into a matrix, then saving the submatrices of the required size as images.

Comment: Matlab is definitely a solution, but more like using a sword where you can do away with a needle :)

Comment: @Vikas - but that's the beauty of MATLAB - it really is like using a needle in this case - the amount of typing required is probably the same as doing so from a command line tool like drewbenn suggested. That's provided you have MATLAB available, of course...